# Cómo centrar el texto de la cabecera con CSS y dejar la flecha de back en la izquierda

Tags: html, css, ionic

Estoy maquetando el header de una pantalla de móvil. Hay un título de la pantalla que debería quedar centrado y una flecha para volver atrás, adjunto imagen de como debería ser:

[image: Diseño de como debería ser el header]

Pero al realizar el código con HTML el resultado es este:

[image: Header maquetado]

No consigo alinear solo uno de los dos elementos ni alinearlo en vertical. adjunto el código.

HTML

```
<ion-navbar class="formHeader" color="talkColor">
    <ion-icon class="navArrow2" name="md-arrow-round-back"></ion-icon>
    <ion-title class="tituloTab">Formulario de afinidad</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

CSS

```
 .formHeader {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navArrow2 {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: center;


}

.tituloTab {
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  vertical-align: center;

}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías crear tres `div` el el primero pones la Flecha en el segundo el titulo y en el tercero un espacio y le das los estilos correspondientes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS) al rescate!

Lo que puedes hacer es aplicarle a tu navbar las propiedades `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` para centrar todo el contenido. Sí quieres centrar verticalmente no te sirve `vertical-align` ya que solo se aplica a los elementos **inline** y **table-cell**, [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) la documentación (en inglés). Y finalmente para la flecha podemos usar `position: absolute` y asignarle una posicion al número de pixeles que tu desees desde su izquierda

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```css
.formHeader {
  /* La magia de FLEX */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Alto de la barra, en tu caso sería 50px */
  height: 60px;
  
  /* Color para el demo */
  background-color: rgb(83, 33, 168);
}

.navArrow2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 25px;
}

.tituloTab {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<navbar class="formHeader" color="talkColor">
  <i class="navArrow2" name="md-arrow-round-back">&larr;</i>
  <h1 class="tituloTab">Formulario de afinidad</h1>
</navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías usar también es bootstrap para poder posicionar, los elementos como "row" en este caso que se ordenen como fila.

```css
.col-2{
  background-color: red;
}
.col-8{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
    <div class="col-2"> <-- </div>
    <div class="col-8 text-center">datos</div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div>
<body>
</html>
```

cuando uso esto me refiero a col-sm-12 ocupo el total del body en este caso si yo pongo que el body tiene 200px de ancho, los div que están dentro se adaptan.

Ahora si quieres hacerlo de forma manual te recomiendo que lo hagas así.
Usar flex de css te permite hacer que se adapte y quede responsivo y especialmente para celulares y esas cosas.

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
```

estas lineas permiten usar flexbox, en terminos simples esto seria como la configuración inicial, `display: flex;` esta linea dice que tu caja(div de clase flex), sea flexible, por lo tanto todos los elementos dentro de el seran flexibles.La otra linea `flex-direction: row;` me dice que todos los elementos dentro de el se posicionen en fila.

Ahora la clase .flex puede ser cualquier nombre, pero si tiene que tener las propiedades que te di arriba.

```html
​<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <style>

   .flex
   {
      
      width: 350px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #555;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
   }

    #flecha{
      width:20%;
      background : #009246;
    }
    #centro{
      width:60%;
      background : #F1F2F1;
    }
    #derecha{
      width:20%;
      background : #CE2B37;
    }
   </style>
    
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Flexbox</p>
  <div class="flex">
    <div id="flecha"></div>
    <div id="centro"></div>
    <div id="derecha"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Espero que te ayude.Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

solo tienes que agregar esto a tu `CSS`.

Luego tienes que jugar un poco con el `top` y `left` de `.navArrow2`, yo le he puesto 25px porque hay un height de 50, pero no estoy totalmente seguro de que quede centrado

Igual para `.tituloTab`, ponle la propiedad `absolute`

```
.formHeader {
  /*tu código aquí*/
  position: relative;
}

.navArrow2 {
  /*tu código aquií*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solución Rápida**

La solución más práctica es agregar `float: left;` a tu elemento `.navArrow2`

---

**Explicación**

Lo que pasa en tu código es que los elementos hijo de `.formHeader` tienen el estilo `display:block`, esto hace que tanto la flecha como el titulo se conviertan en cajas que ocupan todo el ancho de la página.

*Puedes aprender más sobre la propiedad* `display` *[aquí](http://www.google.com/)*

---

**Solución Óptima**

Sin embargo puedes mejorar tus estilos ordenándolos de esta forma:

```
    .formHeader {
        color: white;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navArrow2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .tituloTab {
        margin:auto;
        vertical-align: middle;     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Según creo entender tu necesidad es un [titulo centrado con HTML](https://juanmcastro.es/tutoriales/como-centrar-texto-en-html/) en la parte superior y luego el botón volver en la parte izquierda. Te adjunto código que puede servirte:

```css
.formHeader {
    height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 194);
  width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.navArrow2 {
  color: white;
    width: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.tituloTab {
    color: white;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 15px;

}
.tituloTab a{
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="formHeader" color="talkColor">
    <div class="navArrow2" name="md-arrow-round-back" align="center">  </div>
    <div class="tituloTab" align="center"><a href="https://juanmcastro.es/tutoriales/como-centrar-texto-en-html/">Texto centrado con HTML</a></div>
</div>
```